# Sqlalchemy: get python class from sqlalchemy.schema.MetaData

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

I'm trying to prepopulate lists of objects associateds. So for a specific mapped class, I list all tables with :

ExampleClass is my mapped python class, for example.

```
name = ExampleClass.__name__
tables = [x for x in ExampleClass.metadata.tables.keys() if x != name ]
```

So, I got the tables name but  how can I get the class associated with that tables?

Is it possible?

I'm using the declarative way to map the table and class.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might also consider to keep track of your mapped classes in a dict where the keys are the table names. That's the workaround I use.

Answer (score 1):

I found this way passing the table name param found in list tables

```
def __find_class(self, table):
        for x in mapperlib._mapper_registry.items():
            if x[0].mapped_table.name == table:
                return x[0].class_
```